# DateTime class doing wrong conversion of Timestamp?

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp, converters

The following code is producing a wrong conversion of a Timestamp (`1350553368`):

```
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$dateTime->setTimeStamp(1350553368);    
echo $dateTime->format('F n, Y');
```

PHP converts it to **October 10, 2012**:  http://codepad.viper-7.com/clum0f

However, that timestamp is actually for **October 18, 2012**: http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

I'm sure it's me, and not PHP, so what am I doing wrong?  The code is pretty straightforward, so I can't figure it out.

Comment: `n` means month without a leading 0

Comment: @Programmer - why don't you accept one of the answers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using format `'F n, Y'`. `n` is a numeric representation of the month (October is month 10). Use `d` (leading zeroes) or `j` (no leading zeroes). See [PHP `date()` reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
echo $dateTime->format('F d, Y');
```

Comment: Glad it worked! Don't forget to accept the answer if it's helpful! ;)

Answer (score 2):

[Form PHP DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

- `n` = Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros
- `d` = Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros

You should replace

```
  $dateTime->format('F n, Y');
```

With

```
  $dateTime->format('F d, Y');
```